# Did anybody try to install iOS 4.3 on iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have to test my application in iOS 4.3 environment (using iPhone 3G, as this is the latest device I have with me now).

It seems Apple hasn't released iOS 4.3 beta for iPhone 3G.

Did anybody try to install iOS 4.3 on iPhone 3G?

Do we have to have iPhone 4 or 3GS in-order to test in iOS 4.3 environment?

Please provide your inputs.

Thanks

Kish

Comment: Note that iOS 4.3 is a beta, and as such is still under NDA.  I'd recommend using Apple's official support forums for these kinds of discussions:  http://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: Also, OS-specific discussions might be better handled on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I know this link is very old but wanted to say there is a way to get IOS 4.3 onto iphone 3g.
Here is a link to read and download the source

http://www.whited00r.com/iphone-3g/

Answer (score 1):

**The new build of iOS (version 4.3) drops support for iPhone 3G and 2nd gen iPod touch.**
Only the following devices are supported as of Beta 1:

- iPad
- iPhone 4
- iPhone 3GS
- iPod touch (4th gen)
- iPod touch (3rd gen)

[image]

There has been no indication that this may change for the final release. Other versions of iOS 4 have proven to be unusably slow and otherwise problematic on the iPhone 3G. That they have finally dropped support for them altogether does not come as much of a surprise.

You'll need to upgrade your hardware if you want to beta test the new version of iOS.